# Python3 finding value from excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlsx

I have an Excel file with one worksheet

Example:

```
A                   B  C

Australia

minimum temperature 3  1

average temperature 6  5

Great Britain

minimum temperature 2  7

average temperature 9  2


result:

Australia - 3; Great Britain - 2
```

How to find minimum temperature in Australia in column `B`, average temperature in Great Britain in column `C` and record result in dictionary?
This seems like a pretty simple task, but I can not understand and find examples.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use xlrd to read excel. Other package is also suitable. It depends.

```
import xlrd
data = xlrd.open_workbook('your excel file path')
table = data.sheets()[0] # assume that your data is in the 1st sheet
nrows = table.nrows # get the rows in the table
data_dict = {}
for i in range(nrows):
    if i == 0:
        countinue # ignore the first row 'A B C'
    row = table.row_values(i) # get the data in the ith row
    if (i - 1) % 3 == 0:
        data_dict[row[0]] = {} # a dict whose key is column A's value
        country_name = row[0]
    else:
        data_dict[country_name][row[0]] = {}
        data_dict[country_name][row[0]]['B'] = row[1]
        data_dict[country_name][row[0]]['C'] = row[2]
```

Then you can get the result like data_dict['Australia']['minimum temperature']['B'] = 3

Could u plz give me a more clear format? "minimum temperature 3 1" which one is the minimum?

And I will complement the code...

Comment: for Australia minimal 3, for Great Britain  2

Comment: what's the meaning of the C column for minimum temperature. like the "1" for what? So the element you want to get is dict['Australia']['minimum temperature']['B'] = 3?

Comment: This is for example. I want to get the result as described above